# object becomes null when passed to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, nsobject

In the iOS application, I need to pass an object from one view controller to another and then switch to the new view controller. The goal is to simply relay the information. However, the object becomes `NULL` and is devoid of any information when the next view showed up. what? could be the reason?

Below is part of my code.

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   BIDCourse *course = self.courses[indexPath.row];


   NSString *sub = course.subject;

   BIDSubjectMainTwoViewController *subjectController=[[BIDSubjectMainTwoViewController alloc] init];

   subjectController.title = sub;


   subjectController.course=course;

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:subjectController animated:YES];
}
```

`BIDCourse *course` is my custom subclass to `NSObject`, which has some `NSStrings`, and it's not nil, but when I pass it onto the next view controller, it becomes `NULL`.

Comment: What kind of memory management are you using? ARC? And how is your course property setup? Most likely the course object is deallocated before it is used. Please add some more code, to make this visible.

Comment: synthesize the object course.

Comment: are you allocating course somewhere in the code? i was also having the same problem one, its just you have to allocate it first!

Comment: using ARC, course property: @property (strong, nonatomic) BIDCourse *course; and I did synthesize course

Comment: yes I did. The course object from above gets its value from the self.courses NSMutableArray which contains BIDCourse *gr12English=[[BIDCourse alloc] initWithSubject:@"English" andGrade:12 andTeacher:@"Ms.Dawson" andAvgToPass:60 andNumberOfQuiz:10 andQuizWorth:1 andNumberOfTest:5 andTestWorth:7 andMidtermWorth:25 andFinalWorth:30];
        BIDCourse *gr11math=[[BIDCourse alloc] initWithSubject:@"Mathematics" andGrade:11 andTeacher:@"Mr.Matheson" andAvgToPass:55 andNumberOfQuiz:6 andQuizWorth:2 andNumberOfTest:8 andTestWorth:7 andMidtermWorth:10 andFinalWorth:22];

Comment: self.courses= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:gr12English,gr11math,nil];

Comment: Did override method [BIDSubjectMainTwoViewController setCourse]? When and how you determine that 'course' of your controller is released?

Comment: the problem is most likely in your BIDSubjectMainTwoViewController. can you post the code for this class showing relevant references to course property?

Comment: @SiTeFeng  your problem is solved or not? if solved then accept the answer, give some feedback on stackOverflow. plz accept any one answer from below.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have met a problem like you , when I pass a object to another viewController , it has been released.

I think this is a defect of ARC , ARC think your `subjectController` may be no use , so it release the `subjectController`. Make your `subjectController` as a property , so ARC will not release when you pass it to another viewController.

such as :

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
BIDCourse *course = self.courses[indexPath.row];


NSString *sub = course.subject;

_subjectController=[[BIDSubjectMainTwoViewController alloc] init];

_subjectController.title = sub;


_subjectController.course=course;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:_subjectController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: it looks as though this would work for my case as well, but it didn't work. What's weird is that my NSLog checking "course" in the new view controller came before the one that put in the above delegate method like this        2013-04-25 05:12:07.681 Marks[71737:c07] course: (null)
2013-04-25 05:12:07.684 Marks[71737:c07] course: subject:English  numQ: 10  Quizworth: 1  numTest: 5  testworth: 7  midworth: 25  finalworth: 30

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem lie in BIDSubjectMainTwoViewController.m?

```
subjectController.title = sub;
subjectController.course = course;
```

in your `BIDSubjectMainTwoViewController.m` file, did you @synthesize your properties?

```
@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize course = _course;
```

You could also pass the variables along with an init function ala:

**BIDSubjectMainTwoViewController.h**

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
          andCourse:(BIDCourse *)course;
```

**BIDSubjectMainTwoViewController.m**

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
          andCourse:(BIDCourse *)course
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _title=title;
        _course = course;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but when I tried using the initWithTitle.. method, the problem still remains

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this similar behavior.  My solution was to make a copy of the object.  For your case:

```
BIDCourse *course = [self.courses[indexPath.row] copy];
```

And make sure you implement  copyWithZone in the BIDCourse .m fike.

```
 -(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*) zone
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

BIDSubjectMainTwoViewController.h

```
    NSString *strTemp;

    @property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *strTemp;

    -(void) setValuestrTemp : (NSString *) str;
```

.m file

```
    @synthesize strTemp;
```

// Write setter method

```
    -(void) setValuestrTemp : (NSString *) str {
        self.strTemp = str;
    }
```

and use strTemp in viewWillAppear.

//Now use it

```
    BIDSubjectMainTwoViewController *subjectController=[[BIDSubjectMainTwoViewController alloc] init];

       [subjectController setValuestrTemp:sub];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_subjectController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   NSString *sub = [course.subject copy];
   subjectController.course=[course copy];
```

implement delegate in  `BIDCourse`

```
 -(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*) zone
```